# Contar quantos campos estão em branco em uma linha do MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Eu tenho uma tabela de cadastro com 53 colunas (endereço, telefone, etc).

Eu queria montar uma consulta que me trouxesse quantas dessas colunas estão vazias ou NULL, como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Leandro, a minha resposta foi útil, resolveu seu problema?

Comment: Não é resposta para a pergunta, mas provavelmente o que você precisa é repensar no formato da tabela.

Comment: @Leandro, conseguiu resolver??

Answer (score 3):

Não sei se entendi muito bem, mas, acredito que se você contar os registros usando a cláusula *COUNT(*)* e onde as colunas são nulas ***IS NULL*** e vazias **=''**, você consiga encontrar o esperado. Por exemplo:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tabela WHERE (coluna1 IS NULL or coluna1 = '') 
AND (coluna2 IS NULL or coluna2 = '') 
AND (coluna3 IS NULL or coluna3 = '') ... -- AND a quantidade de colunas que você desejar adiocionar na sua query.
```

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: se entendi a pergunta, ele quer saber, por exemplo, que na linha um tem cinco campos não preenchidos.. se entendi a resposta, está dizendo que existem 10 linhas com campos em branco..

Comment: @rLinhares vamos aguardar a resposta dele, perguntei se a resposta sanou o problema...

Answer (score 1):

Baseando no que entendi (*quantos campos de cada usuário não foram preenchidos*), fiz o seguinte código (dá uma olhada nesse [fiddle funcional](https://rextester.com/NWA62456)):

```
create table tabela_colunas (id int, coluna varchar(100));
CREATE TABLE tabela_contador (id_na_tabela int(10), total int(1));

SET @id_tabela:=1, @total:=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tabela_colunas);

insert into tabela_contador (id_na_tabela, total)
select id, 0 as total from tabela;

WHILE @id_tabela <= @total DO

    set @sql := concat('update tabela_contador tc join tabela t on tc.id_na_tabela = t.id set tc.total = tc.total + 1 where ', (select coluna from tabela_colunas where id = @id_tabela), ' is null or ', (select coluna from tabela_colunas where id = @id_tabela), ' = \'\'');

    PREPARE myquery FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE myquery;

    SET @id_tabela = @id_tabela + 1;    
END WHILE;

select * from tabela_contador;
```

Segui a seguinte lógica:

- criei uma tabela temporárias para armazenar os nomes das colunas;
- criei outra tabela temporárias para armazenar os totais de cada ocorrência da tabela original;
- para cada das colunas, é somado um ao total (quando `id` é o mesmo e o campo não tem valor);
- por fim, consulta da tabela de dado.